# Need help I'm new to php this error keeps on popping up Notice: Undefined index: age

Tags: php, html

This is my form

```
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
    Cost: <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="Cost">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $costErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Model of the Car: <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Ex. Mustang">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $modelErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Age of the Car
    <select name="age">
        <option value="1 Year">1 Year</option>
        <option value="2 Year">2 Years</option>
        <option value="3orso">3 Years to 7 years</option>
        <option value="8orso">8 Years to 10 years</option>
        <option value="10orso">More Than ten years</option><br>
    </select>
    Good Condition
    <select name="conditon">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Notice: Undefined index: age: this is where something gets wrong
        Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 67

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 75

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 91

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 99

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 115

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 123

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 131

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\Try.php on line 139

```
if ($_POST["age"] === "1 Year" && $_POST["conditon"] === "Yes") { 
    echo "Your car Costs " .$cost;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The model of your car is " .$model;
    echo "<br>";
    $price = $cost - ($cost * .20)  ;
    echo "The Car now costs " .$price;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the result of the approach to keep html form and form processing logic in the same file. Do not do that! Keep separate things separate. The specific issue arises when you initially request the form, at that point in time no POST values exist. You could check that with a condition, but mich better is to keep the two things apart, so in separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `$_POST["age"]` is not set when you call the page the first time.
You should add a check `if(!empty($_POST)) {` around all code that handles the form submission. That would be the second block of code you show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST["age"]) && isset($_POST["conditon"]))
{
if ($_POST["age"] === "1 Year" && $_POST["conditon"] === "Yes"){ 
        echo "Your car Costs " .$cost;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "The model of your car is " .$model;
        echo "<br>";
        $price = $cost - ($cost * .20)  ;
        echo "The Car now costs " .$price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should keep it separately but if You want to keep it that way You can solve this problem by adding `isset` to your condition.

Example:

```
if (isset($_POST["age"]) && $_POST["age"] === "1 Year" && $_POST["conditon"] === "Yes"){ 
        echo "Your car Costs " .$cost;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "The model of your car is " .$model;
        echo "<br>";
        $price = $cost - ($cost * .20)  ;
        echo "The Car now costs " .$price;
    }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: By separate u mean separate page? sorry I just learned php 2 days ago